# Applying and checking Metadata during document upload

Tags: file-upload, metadata

I'm trying to do something a bit special with document upload to apply metadata sourced from external systems (This will either be in a list or in a database table).
The behavior I want is that the uploading user can

1. Enter a number, which will be used to search the list, and to fill in multiple pieces of metadata (So if the number was a staff ID number the search could also populate the first name, surname using other fields from the list)
2. Return the results of the search to the user so they can confirm that they typed the right number in (If not they should be able to try again until they're happy)
3. Once OK the user can click to save the document to check it in.

I've been playing around with:

a- lookups- but want the user to type, not select (there could be over 100k IDs)
b- managed metadata- seems like overkill

Does anyone have ideas of how to achieve this? We'd prefer lowest customisation.

Thanks

Martin